# Where exactly is the Morse code character ";" defined?

Tags: cw, history, morse-code

I've seen that quite often in Morse code tables (for example [here](http://www.qsl.net/w5www/morsecode.html)), under punctuation, a semicolon ";"character is listed.

However, the [ITU-R M.1677-1](https://www.itu.int/dms_pubrec/itu-r/rec/m/R-REC-M.1677-1-200910-I!!PDF-E.pdf) doesn't specify that character as a part of the International Morse code.

So my question is: Where is the semicolon character actually defined?

Comment: I think you might be on to something; `–·–·–·`, `NNN` being equivalent to `;` might actually not be standardized.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not a defined part of the International Morse Code, it is a procedural sign similar to AR. As such it is not necessarily the same everywhere, there are several prosigns that vary slightly between Americans and Europeans, for example. The exclamation point springs to mind as an undefined and somewhat variable example.

Some websites show -.-.-. and some show -.-.- for the semicolon, which seems to indicate a similar issue to the exclamation point.

Comment: What I'm looking for are documents that actually define semicolon.

Comment: I think the point is that such character are undefined by any standards organization, and all we have are ad hoc agreements.

Comment: @AndrejaKo there very likely aren't any. It's slang.